# How to make folders like "System Volume Information" or "RECYCLER" hidden, just like it is on windows?

Tags: windows, nautilus, ntfs, hidden-files

I have this external hard drive, and I used it in windows, now that I use it on Ubuntu, and it is kind of annoying to see files like `System Volume Information`, so how can I make it hidden?
Or how can I make any file hidden?

Comment: How can I use the .hidden feature in Nautilus with a filename with multiple words? I was able to hide RECICLER by listing it in .hidden, but not System Volume Information. I tried using quotation marks (i.e."System Volume Information") and / between the words with and without spaces after them (i.e. System/ Volume/ Information and System/Volume/Information. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in linux, hidden attribute of windows doesn't work.

To hide a file/folder, you put a `.` infront of file name.

But **As those folder are system folder in windows, renaming them with `.` may cause damage to the OS stability or windows may create another folder with name which will be again visiable in linux**

So you have to live with that. :)

Comment: that's hard to live with that.. but i put "." and they got invisible, thank you! :) i'm not gonna be using windows much anymore, ubuntu has everything.. but only the games that windows has.. and it doesn't even open with wine.. and this sucks :(

Answer (score 20):

Just create text file `.hidden` on your external hard drive, and add folders you wish to hide, like this:

```
found.000
$RECYCLE.BIN
RECYCLER
System Volume Information
```

After that make sure to refresh the view (<kbd>F5</kbd>) and the folders should now be invisible.

PS. if you wish to see/hide hidden files/folders press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>.

Comment: Refresh didn't do it for me. I had to close and reopen the nautilus window or change directories (on 16.04)

Comment: This is a much nicer way to achieve this than prepending a `.` before each folder, IMHO

Comment: Also, works with the Dolphin file manager on Arch. Much nicer solution than prepending a period.

Comment: Can confirm this also works with the caja file manager.

Comment: @joelnb This works with caja file manager

Answer (score 4):

Although you can make any file/folder hidden by prepending a dot to his name, it is not a good idea to do so on files/folders that belong to another operating system, and that could turn the alien system unstable.

Nautilus, Ubuntu's file browser/manager, has a feature that allows hidding arbitrary files and folders without having to resort to changing their names:

Simply create a `.hidden` file in the root of the affected partition or directory, and list in there the names of the files you want to be hidden on Nautilus user interface.

Comment: And [here's a guide](http://askubuntu.com/questions/235091/make-multiple-files-hidden/235097#235097) how to automate this. Please note that some restrictions apply to this method. `.hidden` files only get interpreted by a few Linux file managers (including the standard one Ubuntu ships with, Nautilus). You will still be able to see the files from the terminal and applications that don't support the `.hidden` method.