# Make multiple files hidden?

Tags: command-line, hidden-files

I have a group of files I want hidden to avoid clutter. Is there a command that can simply make multiple files hidden? Is there an application? Is there a single command that will make the files I've listed hidden?

Thanks.

Comment: In case you don't know, to make a file hidden, you will need to rename it to start with a period.  So, the first question is... can the files be renamed without causing problems with accessing them?  I'm guessing not, as if they could, they could also just be moved into a subdirectory, which would be easy.

Comment: MHC's solution seems like the better alternative if avoiding clutter is the only objective. Renaming files may cause undesired behaviour as indicated by Marty in a comment above.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Linux convention is to rename them to start with a `.`. Most programs, including Nautilus (the GNOME file browser), Dolphin (KDE), and command-line programs like `ls` and Bash's shell globbing, will then hide them (by default).

To rename multiple files simultaneously, you could use any of several graphical tools:

- [`pyrenamer`](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/pyrenamer/)
- [`purrr`](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/purrr/)
- [KRename](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/krename/)
- [nautilus-renamer](https://launchpad.net/nautilus-renamer)
- [GPRename](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gprename/)

In PyRenamer, select your files, activate the "Insert / Delete" tab, and tell it to insert a `.` at position 1:

[image: Sample pyrenamer]

From the command-line, the conventional way is to use `mv` and `find` (if needed). If you have only a few specific files you want to hide, run:

```
for f in file0 file1 file2 file3; do mv "$f" ".$f"; done
```

to append a `.` to each file's names.

If you have several similarly-named files you want to hide (e.g. any file starting with `hideme`), use shell globbing:

```
for f in hideme*; do mv "$f" ".$f"; done
```

Comment: Renaming files is bad when you can just add those filenames to a file called `.hidden` where Nautilus responds to and makes them hidden ;)

Comment: @Rinzwind: That seems to be specific to Nautilus though. The files still show up with `ls` and in Dolphin, and (worse) with shell globbing.

Answer (score 8):

There's a nautilus script for that:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

# Hide-Unhide-In-Nautilus.sh
# Creator: Inameiname
# Date: 21 June 2011
# Version: 1.0
#
#
# This is a simple nautilus script to automatically add file(s)/folder(s)
# to a ".hidden" file so Nautilus will hide them, just like ".*" files
# Instructions:
# - decide what file(s)/folder(s) you want to hide inside a particular folder,
# - highlight them, and right click and select the script
# - it will automatically add the filenames to a created ".hidden" file inside the directory
# - if ".hidden" isn't there, it will add it
# - if you decide to unhide things, simply highlight and select the script again,
# - and it will automatically remove the filenames from the ".hidden" file
# - if ".hidden" contains no filenames, it will remove it
#
#
# Optionals:
# - Add the option to change the owner and group for whatever is selected to hide/unhide
# - Add the option to add the permissions for whatever is selected to hide/unhide
# - Add the option to make executable whatever is selected to hide/unhide
#
#
# Remember this only works inside the current directory/opened folder and files/folders inside that folder.
# Just comment out or uncomment whatever desired.
# Currently, only the ability to hide/unhide stuff is uncommented,
# but you can always just comment it out, and uncomment one of the "Make Executable" commands,
# and/or one of the "Change the owner and/or group of each file" commands,
# and/or one of the "Add permissions" commands, or mix and match whatever you want.
#
#
# For the changes to take effect to the file(s)/folder(s) you hid/unhid, you may have to refresh the folder, or even Nautilus



# Set IFS so that it won't consider spaces as entry separators.
# Without this, spaces in file/folder names can make the loop go wacky.
IFS=$'\n'

# See if the Nautilus environment variable is empty
if [ -z $NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS ]; then
    # If it's blank, set it equal to $1
    NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS=$1
fi

# Loop through the list (from either Nautilus or the command line)
for ARCHIVE_FULLPATH in $NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS; do
    NEWDIRNAME=${ARCHIVE_FULLPATH%.*}
    FILENAME=${ARCHIVE_FULLPATH##*/}
    NAME=${ARCHIVE_FULLPATH##*/.*}

    # Hide/Unhide file(s)/folder(s) using ".hidden" file within the current folder
      # Copies all selected files/folders filenames to ".hidden"
        echo $FILENAME >> .hidden
      # Sorts and Checks ".hidden" for any duplicates
        sort .hidden | uniq -u > .hidden_temp
        rm .hidden
        mv .hidden_temp .hidden
      # Checks ".hidden" to see if there is anything there; if not, it removes it
        for file in .hidden
        do
          if [ `wc -l < $file` -eq 0 ]; then
             # file is empty
             rm $file
          fi
        done
    # Change the owner and/or group of each FILE to OWNER and/or GROUP, if desired
      # chown -R $USER:$USER $ARCHIVE_FULLPATH # set owner:group to current user
      # gnome-terminal -x sudo chown -R root:root $ARCHIVE_FULLPATH # set owner:group to root
      # gnome-terminal -x sudo chown -R $USER:$USER $ARCHIVE_FULLPATH # set owner:group to current user
    # Add permissions, if desired
      # chmod 444 $ARCHIVE_FULLPATH # read-only permissions for all
      # chmod 600 $ARCHIVE_FULLPATH # read/write for you, no permissions for rest
      # chmod 644 $ARCHIVE_FULLPATH # read/write for you, read-only permissions for rest (default)
      # sudo chmod 444 $ARCHIVE_FULLPATH # read-only permissions for all
      # sudo chmod 600 $ARCHIVE_FULLPATH # read/write for you, no permissions for rest
      # sudo chmod 644 $ARCHIVE_FULLPATH # read/write for you, read-only permissions for rest (default)
    # Make executable, if desired
      # chmod +x $ARCHIVE_FULLPATH
      # gnome-terminal -x sudo chmod +x $ARCHIVE_FULLPATH

done

# Add a notification when finished, if desired
    notify-send -t 2000 -i /usr/share/icons/gnome/32x32/status/info.png "Job Finished"
```

Source: http://gnomefiles.org/content/show.php/Easily+Hide+Files%2BFolders+in+Nautilus?content=142912

---

Copy and paste the contents of the code box above into a new document. Save it and rename it to *Hide or Unhide*. Make it executable (right click --> *Properties* --> *Permissions* --> *Allow executing file as program*). Then move the file to `~/.gnome2/nautilus-scripts`.

You should now be able to access the script from your nautilus context menu. Just right click on any file(s) you want to hide or unhide and select *Scripts* --> *Hide or Unhide*. You will have to reload the folder (<kbd>F5</kbd>) to see the changes

The advantage of this method (besides it ease of use) is that it doesn't rename the files.

Answer (score 0):

To perform the same operation as the Nautilus Script mentioned above, it's also possible to add **Hide/Unhide** menu to Nautilus by installing the **nautilus-actions-extra package** via the **PPA channel** here: https://launchpad.net/~nae-team/+archive/ppa