# Script for hiding files

Tags: scripts

I recently found a script for hiding desktop files and folders. The following is the script:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
#
cd /home/ramvignesh/Desktop
for f in `ls`; do
mv "$f" ".$f"
done
```

The script isn't working properly. It is not hiding the files named with spaces in them. 
For example, If I have a file named 'Untitled Document', I get the following errors. . .

```
mv: cannot stat ‘Untitled’: No such file or directory
mv: cannot stat ‘Document’: No such file or directory
```

Please let me know why the script behaves in such a way. Can anyone correct the script for me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: And if you have in your directory `file` and `.file` for a start, you silently loose the second one. Very dangerous scripts...

Comment: Is there a script a safer script?

Comment: @Ramvignesh Yes. Try [this one](http://askubuntu.com/a/235097/81372) out.

Comment: It's evidently written by inexperienced linux user. It's using ls to list files. That's one. Second,  you wouldn't loose files named with leading dot because by default ls shows only non-hidden files. You need `ls -a` for that. A.B in his answer uses `rename` which is better approach.

Answer (score 2):

The script that you found is flawed with parsing output of `ls` command (you can read about why you shouldn't use `ls` in scripting [here](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)).

A better approach is to use `find` command and pipe its output to `xargs`.

Since in the original script you operate on the files that are in a specific directory, I've tailored the command accordingly. Navigate to the directory where you want to hide the files and run the part bellow:

`find . -maxdepth 1 -type f ! -name  ".*" -printf "%f\0" | xargs -0 -I file mv file .file`

Here is a small demo in my home directory. I create 3 files and use above command to hide them.

```
$ touch file1 file2 file3


$ find . -maxdepth 1 -type f ! -name  ".*" -printf "%f\0" | xargs -0 -I file mv file .file 


$ ls -a
./             .bash_logout  Desktop/    .file1   .gnupg/        .macromedia/  Pictures/  .ssh/        .xsession-errors
../            .bashrc       .dmrc       .file2   .ICEauthority  .mkshrc       .profile   Templates/   .xsession-errors.old
.adobe/        .cache/       Documents/  .file3   .lesshst       .mozilla/     .psensor/  Videos/
.bash_history  .config/      Downloads/  .gconf/  .local/        Music/        Public/    .Xauthority
```

The above works for files. To make it work for directories, simply change `-type f` to `-type d`.

Demo:

```
$ ls
dirone/  dirthree/  dirtwo/


$ find . -maxdepth 1 -type d ! -name  ".*" -printf "%f\0" | xargs -0 -I file mv file .file                                                           


$ ls


$ ls -a
./  ../  .dirone/  .dirthree/  .dirtwo/
```

Comment: Needs av upvote :)

Answer (score 0):

Using `rename` and a little script with the name `hide_desktop_files`.

```
#!/bin/bash
dir="$PWD"
cd ~/Desktop
rename 's/(.*)/.$1/' *
cd "$dir"
```

---

*Example*

```
% ls -ogla ~/Desktop
total 92
drwxr-xr-x   3  4096 Aug 15 20:45 .
drwxr-xr-x 236 86016 Aug 15 20:46 ..
-rw-rw-r--   1     0 Aug 15 20:45 bar
-rw-rw-r--   1     0 Aug 15 20:45 foo
drwxrwxr-x   2  4096 Aug 15 20:45 .foo

% ./hide_desktop_files                
rename(bar, .bar)
foo not renamed: .foo already exists

% ls -ogla ~/Desktop
total 92
drwxr-xr-x   3  4096 Aug 15 20:45 .
drwxr-xr-x 236 86016 Aug 15 20:47 ..
-rw-rw-r--   1     0 Aug 15 20:45 bar
-rw-rw-r--   1     0 Aug 15 20:45 foo
drwxrwxr-x   2  4096 Aug 15 20:45 .foo
```